# MYSQL LEFT JOIN - Filter by User

Tags: mysql, filter, null, left-join, inner-join

Any Idea why i can't filter this query by using an ID?
I need that query with the Value NULL (if is it not available).
That doesnt work:

```
SELECT lektions_themen.titel, lektions_themen.id,
lektions_themen.subtitel,lektions_themen.bild,
user_lektion.email
 FROM `user_lektion`

INNER JOIN lektions_themen
ON
user_lektion.kurs_id=lektions_themen.kurs_id
WHERE user_lektion.id=$id
```

here is an Example:

```
LECTIONS
#id             #title#
1               Mathe
2               Latin
3               English
4               Greek

USER        
#UserLectionID  #Name   #UserId     #lectionId
2               Fritz   1           2
3               Fritz   1           3
4               Paul    2           1
5               Paul    2           2

RESULT (userID=1)
#Name   #title
Fritz   NULL
Fritz   Latin   
Fritz   English
Fritz   NULL
```

I need all LECTIONS WITH UserId=1

Answer (score 0):

Ok got it

```
SELECT lektions_themen.titel, lektions_themen.id,
lektions_themen.subtitel,lektions_themen.bild,
user_lektion.email
 FROM `user_lektion`

INNER JOIN lektions_themen
ON
user_lektion.kurs_id=lektions_themen.kurs_id

AND user_lektion.email='$id'
```